# Change text of original author

Tags: mit, copyright, license-notice

I am thinking about using this library: https://github.com/rxi/classic/blob/master/classic.lua

and I have a question regarding the first few lines:

```
--
-- classic
--
-- Copyright (c) 2014, rxi
--
-- This module is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
-- the terms of the MIT license. See LICENSE for details.
--
```

It is illegal to delete the copyright `-- Copyright (c) 2014, rxi` even when the license doesnt require it, right?

and am I allowed to alter following text:

```
-- This module is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
-- the terms of the MIT license. See LICENSE for details.
--
```

to something like:

```
-- You can find the license in /Project/licenses/MIT.license
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly all licenses (including the MIT license) require that you keep the copyright notices intact, either explicitly or by forbidding you to misrepresent the authorship of the code.

For the other part of the comment block you ask about, I would strongly recommend that you keep that as well. It is not that much longer than your replacement and prevents people from guessing what license is used.
You *should* however update the filename/location of the file that contains the full test of the MIT license if you moved/renamed that file.

Answer (score 0):

No, you must keep this notice.

> The MIT license permits reuse within proprietary software provided that all copies of the licensed software include a copy of the MIT License terms and the copyright notice.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License